# [apache-flink]flink crash in production, i can't find the solution of the log

Tags: scala, apache-flink

Here is the last log of the flink, i would like to know the function of TaskManagerStdoutFileHandler

```
2022-05-25 11:45:41.286 ERROR [flink-scheduler-1] o.a.f.r.r.h.t.TaskManagerStdoutFileHandler - Failed to transfer file from TaskExecutor container_e18_1642772346238_0370_01_000002.
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://flink/user/resourcemanager#-857616249]] after [10000 ms]. Message of type [org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.messages.LocalFencedMessage]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:607)
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591)
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990)
 at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:871)
 at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:263)
 at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:261)
 at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:191)
 at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:188)
 at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
 at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:74)
 at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
 at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
 at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scal
```

Comment: I don't know if you're familiar with Actors or not, but basically what happens here, is that an actor named `resourcemanager` is supposed to fetch a resource and send a reply to the actual requester in 10 seconds, and fails for some reason (which will not probably be exposed in the terminal). That's everything the log tries to say, so don't look for anything extra from the logs, instead, try to do some actions and some breakpoints to reproduce the bug and figure out why it happens, that actually might also be a bug in the library.

Comment: it's very hard to reproduce the problem.the job is running for a hundred days.